# Корректный логин при регистрации

Tags: php

Как разрешить пользователю вводить логин только на Английском языке ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот примерно так

```
if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9]+$#i", $field)) {
    die('Разрешены только символы a-z и цифры');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) написать об этом явно, яркими буквами :)

2) на клиенте повесить скрипт, проверяющий поле (СХЕМАТИЧНО):

```
<input name="login" type="text" onkeyup="check_login()">

...
function check_login()
{
    var frm = doc.getElementById('loginform');
    if( !valid_login(frm.login.value) )
    {
        alert( 'Низя!' );
    }
    /* а можно, например, переводить не-ASCII символы в транслит */
}
```

3) проверку на серверной стороне сделать, выше написали

4) задуматься: а надо ли оно? длину логина проверять ещё OK, пробелы там, какие-то зарезервированные логины, но буковки - хуже этого может быть только ограничения на пароль :(

Comment: Так как Вы предложили во втором пункте так лучше не делать!

Comment: Ну не так, а, например, проверять по onsubmit() - не принципиально.  Сама идея ограничивать логин набором латиницы в общем случае дурацкая :)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, никак :)

Вы можете написать JavaScript, который будет обрабатывать нажатие клавиши на поле для ввода (c jQuery):

```
$('#input').keydown( function(e) {    
    if (!isSymbolAllowed(e)) //isSymbolAllowed проверяет разрешён ли символ e
        return false; //если не разрешён, то запрещаем этот символ
    return true;
});
```

Это можно назвать **клиентской валидацией**.

Но даже это Вас не спасёт. Пользователь может отредактировать HTML код страницы вручную, и к Вам на сервер может прийти любая введённая им информация. Поэтому необходимо проводить ещё и **серверную валидацию**.

Answer (score 0):

if (!preg_match("#^[a-zА-z0-9]+$#i", $field)){
      die('Разрешены только символы a-z и цифры');
    }
Этот скрипт,неполный,нехватает больших английских букв.Хотя возможно я неправ, не доконца понял как составлять паттерн для маски.

Comment: Костя Самсин, проще и правильнее всего: [a-zA-Z].

P.S А как отправлять комментарий к чужому ответу?